# How to add a new row to Winforms DataGridView in my custom column

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, designer, datagridviewcolumn

I have made a custom column for my DataGridView which is used in editable mode. While I am entering data in every column, the dataGrid automatically adds a new row as follows :

[image]

But in my custom column it does not happen.

[image]

which part of the custom column is responsible for adding new rows and how should I do that.

**EDIT :** 
I implemented three classes for my custom column  :

```
public class DataGridViewLookupColumn : DataGridViewColumn {...}
public class DataGridViewLookupCell : DataGridViewTextBoxCell{...}
public class DataGridLookupControl : LookupControl, IDataGridViewEditingControl{...}
```

**EDIT :** 
I am filling my DatagridView using a binding source.

```
this.dataGrid.DataSource = BindingSource;
BindingSource.DataSource = model;
model=await this.EntityService.AdvancedSearchAsync(...);
```

above codes are gathered from three diffrent points in application to show structure of my data and application.

Thanks in advance for your time and your consideration of course.

Comment: What `DataSource` you are using. Show a code how `DataGridView` filled with data and how new rows added to the `DataSource`

Comment: Can you show us at least what events your custom Column has implemented?

Comment: @TaW I Edited the question in your response my friend.

Comment: @Fabio the second edit on my question is for you sir.

Comment: Thanks but the classes are more or less obligatory. Interesting differences are which of the many possible events are actually implemented. (And how..). Also add a little description of what the Column does: Is it a search field?

Comment: @TaW the column acts like a Combobox column which has a value member of Id and a display member of Name except for the way it shows the list. this columns opens a form to select data from. the implementation is too long to send here but if a particular part is helpful I will add it.

Comment: Don't post the implementations, just the event & function __names__ so we can see __which__ are coded. Many are optional, others recommended (like Clone). I did a test with a display-only  custom column and it has the same problem, but it is only for display..

Comment: @TaW Thanks for your test. DataGridViewLookupCell : Clone, InitializeEditingControl, and Paint are overrided.

Comment: @TaW thank you my friend. I found the solution as follows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out how to solve it.
It's just

```
DataGridView.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(true);
```

I added this code to my change event and my problem solved.